# How do I take a Screen Shot of a UIView that hasn't been loaded yet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, screenshot

To explain the main features of my iPhone app I want to create a modal view, which shows some screen shots of my app in the background and some explanations on top.

I create the screen shots (in the background) with

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = selectedTab;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.tabBarController.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But some of the views in my tabBarController may not have been fully loaded yet.
Also the layout of almost all views looks distorted in the screen shots.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your app first without the screenshots first. Take real screenshots from the device and annotate them and include them in your app.

If you don't want to do that, then you are stuck.

Comment: When the user opens this documentation later. I would love to have an up to date image.

Comment: I also tried to load the view itself (instead of the screenshot), but this creates a lot of problems :-)